# import with mysql.exe aborts with maximum time execution exceeded

Tags: mysql, mariadb, timeout

Using from XAMPP on Win10

Server version: 10.4.24-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

**mysql -u user -p db**

**source db.sql**

I end up with the error below after way more then 300 seconds.

*Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp-2022-06-09**

I know this error from using **phpmyadmin**, but here  I use **mysql.exe**. Apache is not running.
The directory mentioned in the error text is an old XAMPP installation not used here.

What am i missing ? I have scanned all ini files for mysql and php but have not found any entry specifiymg 300 seconds. I have loaded this huge db in the past but never seen this before.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Neither MariaDB server nor MariaDB command line client have a maximum execution time error message, so please post the complete error message returned by the command line client.

Comment: (84495458, 881955, '650', 3, '', 'a', 'Sicherheit und Ordnung')<br/>
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in <b>D:\xampp-2022-06-09
--------------

ERROR at line 22956803 in file: 'anawuelasis.sql': Unknown command '\l'.
ERROR at line 22956803 in file: 'anawuelasis.sql': Unknown command '\D'.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 22956803 in file: 'anawuelasis.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'lasses\DatabaseInterface.php</b> on line <b>2136</b><br/>' at line 1

Comment: before the above  :   
ERROR at line 22956803 in file: 'anawuelasis.sql': Unknown command '\x'.
--------------
INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `titleid`, `tag`, `seq`, `indicator`, `subfieldcode`, `subfielddata`) VALUES
(84495090, 881953, '650', 1, '', '0', '(DE-101)040567834'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1064 as reported by the command line client is a syntax/parser error.
You don't have any error related to maximum execution time.

If you open db.sql in an editor and search for "Maximum execution time" you will notice, that this message is in your data which you tried to import. Likely PHP stopped after 300 seconds and the error message was stored in this file.

Comment: Yes, db was exported using phpmyadmin. Stupid me !